# Is this the right way to check if user is logged in? Flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I was adding login/register in my app using Firebase. It is working perfectly, but now i wanted to check if the user has already registered and logged in when he opens the app, if that's true then show him the Home page, else show him the Login page. So i did some searching and mostly it's done using the Streambuilder method. But all i did was to check if the user is logged in using

```
initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
              ? Routes.loginScreen
              : Routes.homePage,
```

and it works perfectly, Almost everyone is using the Streambuilder method. So i was curiois am i doing it the wrong way? Is there a better way to do this? Here's the full code btw. Which is working fine, but i just want to know if it's the right way?

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            //Todo Add splashscreen
          );
        }
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "MyApp",
          initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
              ? Routes.loginScreen
              : Routes.homePage,
          onGenerateRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for using streambuilder, is to monitor changes and actually reflect them on your app. This code:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
              ? Routes.loginScreen
              : Routes.homePage,
```

Works properly but only once, when your app runs. It captures the auth state only when your app reaches that line of code. But if afterwards the user is signed out, the app UI does not change, and here is where the added benifit of using a stream comes. If anywhere in your app down the line, you add a sign out button, your user will indeed be logged out, but will still be inside your app. The login screen will not be returned.

Since you are using FirebaseAuth SDK, it's recommended to make the best out of it, as it comes with built in stream such as `idTokenChanges`  , `authStateChanges`, and `userChanges`, they will make your life much easier, and your app code more elegant.

If you want to keep your code like this, it's fine, but make sure that in your loginScreen route, you have a stream, which listens to Auth changes and a pseudo code similar to something like this:

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
          initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
...etc
 if (snapshot.data == null) 
     return LoginScreenLogicWithButtons());
           
 if (snapshot.data != null) 
     return  HomePage();
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! But i added a sign out button which signs you out and made it navigate to the Login screen and it works perfectly. I can re login or create another account and login with either of the accounts, So i guess streambuilder in simple case like login/register or logout isn't necessary. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Hi there, both question and answer are REALLY useful: thank you. I wanted to ask: how about efficiency? How about power-consumption? How many times does the `StreamBuilder` re-build the whole application? I genuinely don't know how to fetch answers for this topic

Comment: Correct, to a certain extent. But if you wanted to sign out your user remotely, they won't be navigated to the login page, because the logout was triggered by something else not your button chained to a navigator function.

Comment: @venir Streambuilders are very efficient, and in regards to power consumption, it's very minimal, you can investigate it in devTools. But when it comes to something like this, even if it were to be a bit `"expensive"`, it's worth it for such an important turning point in the app. I have an app where a boolean called `isBlocked` is stored in my user's document. When an admin blocks a user, a seperate stream somewhere deep in the app is triggered, and it signs the user out, which redirects the user to login and shows them a message they are blocked. Many useful dynamic cases for using a stream.

Comment: Aside from the fact that it is recommended by the flutter team and firebase team as per their documentation, and the firebase team went through plenty of efforts for implementing multiple streams mentioned in my answer, this collaborative effort was done for a reason, and it'd be very interesting to read about them. You'll enjoy it.

Comment: Would you mind linking here such material? Thanks again mate.

Comment: @venir Absoloutely, here you go => https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage